# Confused between Futur 1 and Futur 2

Tags: future

> Ich werde morgen ankommen.

> Ich werde morgen angekommen sein.

Please explain to me in a concrete way how to use Futur 2 when Futur 1 is not usable. I'm really confused and the Internet isn't helping.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when Futur I is not usable"?

Comment: Is English not helping either? There are "will arrive" and "will have arrived" there too.

Comment: VTC, I find the question unclear. Is it about when to use Futur 2 or about how to use it? What is the confusion about? Are you asking why Futur 2 exists when there's Futur I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Futur II* and *Plusquamperfect* are dependent tenses. You only can use them  if you have two events, and the places, where these tenses feel home and comfort are subordinate clauses:

> Wenn du heute Abend heimkommst, werde ich bereits eingeschlafen sein.
> <sub>When you come home tonight, I will have already fallen asleep.</sub>

- **Wenn du heute Abend heimkommst**
  This is the main clause. Grammatically it's in *Präsens,* but *Präsens* also can express events in the past or in the future, like in this case. Coming home is an event in the future.
- **werde ich bereits eingeschlafen sein**
  This is a subordinate clause. It only makes sense together with the main clause, because the main clause provides a point in the future to which the subordinate clause refers. The subordinate clause talks about a moment that will be in the past at this reference point. The moment when I fall asleep will be in the past when you arrive at home.

Comment: +1 for answering this vague question. I just think you got main and subordinate clause mixed up. The subordinate clause starting with "wenn" provides the time frame for the main clause in your example.